# How to pass a date range to awk as a variable

Tags: bash, variables, awk, date-range

Here is my case.

```
bash ~]# TIME="2012-05-25 06:42:57"
bash ~]# echo "2012-05-25 00:16:51,610" | awk -v var=$TIME '{if ($0 < var) print $0}'
```

Then, here is the error message

```
awk: 06:42:57
awk:   ^ syntax error
```

I just want to pass a date range to my awk command. How to archive this? Please help. Thanks.

Modify the case

```
START_TIME="2012-05-24 00:00:00"
END_TIME="2012-05-24 01:00:00"
echo "2012-05-24 00:10:10" | awk -v "START=$START_TIME" -v "END=$END_TIME" '{ if ( $0 > START && $0 < END) print $0 }'
```

It seems not working in IF conditions.

```
awk: { if ( $0 < START && $0 > END) print $0 }
awk:                           ^ syntax error
```

---

### After serval trying, seems found the solution with another approach.

```
echo "2012-05-24 00:10:10" | awk '{ if ( $0 > "'"$START_TIME"'" && $0 < "'"$END_TIME"'" ) print $0 }'
```

Not sure how to do it with awk variable "-v". Anyone have idears?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote your variable when passing it to AWK:

```
echo "2012-05-25 00:16:51,610" | awk -v "var=$TIME" '{if ($0 < var) print $0}'
```

Comment: ... Or just `awk "\$0 < \"$TIME\""` but be careful with the quoting!

Comment: @tripleee: I don't recommend embedding shell variables for just that reason. Using `-v` variable passing prevents those issues.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks, it works in that case, but if I change the case, why it not working ?
    echo "2012-05-24 00:10:10" | awk -v "START=$START_TIME" -v "END=$END_TIME" '{ if ( $0 < START && $0 > END) print $0 }'

Comment: @phyerbarte: `END` is a reserved word in AWK. Try another variable name. Also `$0 < START && $0 > END` doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you mean `$0 > START && $0 < END` or `$0 < START || $0 > END`. You should use lower case or mixed case variable names.

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson, you are right, I cannot use "END" as the variable name in the awk. And yeah, you are right, the logic was reversed...by the way, why it is better to use lower case or mixed case as variable names? Is that can avoid some mistakes or other advantages? Is there some kind of standard exists? If yes, where I can find it? Just wandering how to write shell script with a good style. Like C++ standard from google.etc

Comment: @phyerbarte: Using lower or mixed case variable names in shell scripts reduces the chances of name collision with shell or environment variables. Using them in AWK programs is, at least in part, a carryover from using them in the shell. If you use `end` as your variable instead of `END`, your script will work. This is an example of what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

At least on my system, it appears that "END" is a reserved word even for variables.  Awk uses END as it uses BEGIN, but I hadn't seen attempts to use it as a variable before.  Note:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ START_TIME="2012-05-24 00:00:00"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ END_TIME="2012-05-24 01:00:00"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "2012-05-24 00:10:10" | awk -v "START=$START_TIME" -v "END=$END_TIME" '{ if ( $0 < START && $0 > END) print $0 }'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        { if ( $0 < START && $0 > >>>  END <<< ) print $0 }
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "2012-05-24 00:10:10" | awk -v s_time="$START_TIME" -v e_time="$END_TIME" '{ if ( $0 < s_time && $0 > e_time) print $0 }'
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Obviously this still isn't working, but now it's not working because of a misunderstanding about how comparisons work, rather than because we're trying to use a reserved word as a variable.

Looking at your `if` statement, it seems that you're trying to evaluate TRUE only if the comparison string is both BEFORE the start date and AFTER the end date.  Barring theories of time being circular, I think we can assume that this logic is flawed.

So here's what I came up with.  Note that this uses `gawk`'s `mktime()` function, so it won't work everywhere.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ START_TIME="2012-05-24 00:00:00"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ END_TIME="2012-05-24 01:00:00"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf '2012-05-23 22:10:10\n2012-05-24 00:10:10\n2012-05-24 01:10:10\n' | gawk -v s_time="$START_TIME" -v e_time="$END_TIME" 'BEGIN { s=mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","G",s_time)); e=mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","G",e_time)); } { now=mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","G")); if ( now > s && now < e) print $0 }'
2012-05-24 00:10:10
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Spaced out for easier reading, the gawk script looks like this:

```
BEGIN {
    s=mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","G",s_time));
    e=mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","G",e_time));
}
{
    now=mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]/," ","G"));
    if ( now > s && now < e) print $0;
}
```

Obviously, this relies completely on the fact that your date/time specification matches `mktime()`'s input format so closely.  But it works with the sample data in your question.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti, seems it explain what happend exactlly, yes, the original date logic is wrong, but the key point is I'm using the "END" as the variable name in the awk. mktime is another option to achive my case, thanks again. DennisWilliamson came first, so I will accept his solution.

Comment: @phyerbarte, it seems that Denis didn't mention the cause of your problem (the END reserved word) until after my post, but whatever.  Thanks at least for the upvote.